# Xamarin.Android layout to occupy all the available space?

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, fluid-layout, stretch

Please help me achieve this layout, I need 3 ImageViews and a TextView in the same line with the last two aligned to the right side. I have tried put them into LinearLayout, GridLayout, TableLayout, RelativeLayout but for the love of god I can't figure this out!

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are there any proportions between them?

Comment: Hi, I have seen your code, and updated my answer, please test it.

Comment: Thank you very much, the placing is just perfect! The only problem is, that the imageView2 is at the most right position, not the imageView3. I have an educated guess why is it happening, but i would like to know your solution if possible! thank you!

Comment: Hi, by `that the imageView2 is at the most right position, not the imageView3`, I don't understand it, can you show a picture? Thanks!

Comment: yes, sorry, this is the case now: https://i.imgur.com/3jWj5ty.jpg

Comment: I have changed it, please test it.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### LinearLayout( proportion):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### RelativeLayout( no proportion):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv1"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv3"
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/iv3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Update:

```
        var relativeLayout = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout(this)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent),
            LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Ltr
        };

        var imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
        imageView1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);
        var layoutParams = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        layoutParams.SetMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        imageView1.Id = 1;
        imageView1.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        relativeLayout.AddView(imageView1);


        View childView1 = relativeLayout.GetChildAt(0);
        var textView = new TextView(this)
        {
            Text = "TextView"
        };
        layoutParams = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        layoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, childView1.Id);
        layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        textView.Id = 2;
        textView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        relativeLayout.AddView(textView);

        var imageView3 = new ImageView(this);
        imageView3.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);
        layoutParams = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        layoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentEnd);
        layoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);
        imageView3.Id = 3;
        imageView3.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        relativeLayout.AddView(imageView3);

        View childView2 = relativeLayout.GetChildAt(2);
        var imageView2 = new ImageView(this);
        imageView2.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);
        layoutParams = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        layoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.LeftOf, childView2.Id);
        imageView2.Id = 4;
        imageView2.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        relativeLayout.AddView(imageView2);
```

Comment: I'm deeply sorry, i forgot to mention that i need this programmatically, this is i have so far, following your xml: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/022524177464bd81a6f67a9c73f3f051